# how to resolve error while creating work items using Azure devops API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I need help in creating a work item with the following PowerShell script, however I get this error:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At C:\AutoWICreate1.PS1:64 char:11

- $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -Cont ...
- ```
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebEx
    ception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

---

Below is the script:

```
  param(
       [string]$baseurl = "http://tfs.com:8080/tfs/collection",
       [string]$projectName = "teamproject",
       [string]$keepForever = "true",
       [string]$user = "user-name",
       [string]$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       [string]$title = "POCAutoCreation"
```

)

## Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

```
$value = @"
```

[
{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/System.Title",
"value": $title
},

{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/System.Tags",
"value": "Tag0921;Tag0926;Tag0927;Tag0928"
},

{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity",
"value": "Development"
},

{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort",
"value": "8"
},
{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea",
"value": "Business"
},
{
"op": "add",
"path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity",
"value": "3 - Medium"
},

]
"@

return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"bug?api-version=5.0"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Comment: Could you please check the permissions of your PAT?

Comment: Yes I did and updating the PAT worked Thanks for your time ..

Comment: is there a way in which i can get work items created using this Script referring to an excel or an external reference point ?

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you want to know how to bulk insert work items. If so, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the actual requirement is to create Work Items using the Script i was getting issues with which now works after updating the PAT, now we need to feed this script from an excel sheet placed on my D drive.

Comment: Or May be something like the script mentioned in this url: https://programmaticponderings.com/2012/04/15/automating-task-creation-in-team-foundation-server-with-powershell/ ....... Just need the excel to capture data and the script pulls it from excel and creates work items ..

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can read the work items' fields from excel then create them with these fields in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you share a sample script or solution that i can replicate at my end ?